# Js fetch request reloads the page twice

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I make a POST fetch request with formdata as body, but it reloads the page twice, once when it sends the data and once when it gets back.(it sends to a flask server that sends back a pdf)

Html:

```
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept=".mxl, .mscz" name="file"/>
    <button class="upload" id="upload">Upload</button>
</body>
```

Js:

```
function uploadFile(file) {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: file,
    })
    .then(response => {
       // downloadResponseAsFile(response);
  })
}

function downloadResponseAsFile(response) {
}

const uploadButton = document.querySelector('.upload');
uploadButton.addEventListener('click',(e)  {
  e.preventDefault();
  const fileInput = document.querySelector('#fileInput');     
  const file = fileInput.files[0];
  
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);

  uploadFile(formData);
});
```

When i don't use the formdata or just don't choose the file it works(doesn't reload the page).
If i dont use event listener, just onclick function it is still the same.
What is the cause of this?

EDIT:
It looks like the live server is the one who refreshes the page when I open the file and try to send it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, when I sent the file to the server it was in the same folder as the webpage(stupid thing) and the live server(which hosted the webpage) thought that i changed a file so it refreshed the page. Now I moved the server and webpage to different folders and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your input element with a `<form>` element and before you submit call the `event.preventDefault()` on the form element .
This will prevent the reloading of your page